# Apple Pay - NSS error -8178

Tags: php, curl, public-key, applepay, applepayjs

I'm integrating Apple pay to website in PHP, by following the tutorial in https://github.com/norfolkmustard/ApplePayJS . However I'm getting following error if I click the apple pay button.

```
unable to load client key: -8178 (SEC_ERROR_BAD_KEY)
```

When I checked the error in detail I'm getting below details:

[image]

I even tried disabling the SSL in curl by adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you confirmed you have an active and working key?

Comment: you mean the key generated in the Mac key-chain, then yes.

Comment: Confirm the .pem files you exported to be valid and in use. Also possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20969241/216129

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45545905/216129

Comment: Apparently it's was the problem and I had to add the following code in the curl `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');` . thanks @JariKeinänen

Comment: Prehaps look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280548/curl-doesnt-connect-to-https-while-wget-does-nss-error-12286

Comment: I see it's been, mostly, resolved, just wanted to add to the discussion; WHEN USING PAYMENT FORMS ALWAYS USE SSL, NEVER DISABLE.

Comment: I'm just here to back @Joshua and his claim that you should never disable SSL when processing payments.